# Selecting row names from a data frame using a for loop to subset

Tags: r, dataframe, subset

I have a dataframe outputted from a Principal Component Analysis. The values are the loadings of each principal component.
It is rather large (146 x 146, but here I am coping only a 5 x 5 sample)

```
>loads.df[1:5,1:5]
               PC1         PC2         PC3         PC4         PC5
Lip_1  0.217572293 -0.05501790  0.09627901 -0.04127339  0.06228162
Lip_2 -0.002299654  0.06167777  0.08853237 -0.10357565 -0.18432139
Lip_3  0.213276149 -0.05596983  0.12046149 -0.01380695  0.04328364
Lip_4  0.232908337 -0.07124672  0.10277296 -0.02581120  0.03838504
Lip_5  0.101494133 -0.05313731 -0.00510382  0.07335147 -0.05647190
```

I am interested in finding the max absolute value for the first 22 components and extract the row names for each of it. To make myself clearer, using the following code I can extract the row name of max absolute value for the column PC1:

```
> rownames(loads.df[loads.df$PC1 == abs(max(loads.df$PC1)), ])
[1] "Lip_10"
```

Since I am only interested in the first 22 components I could repeat the command 22 times and change the column name, but I was trying to find a solution using a for loop.

This is what I tried, but it didn't  really return what I hope it would:

```
pc <- paste("PC",1:22, sep="")
for(i in pc){
  print(rownames(loads.df[loads.df$i == abs(max(loads.df$i)), ]))
}
character(0)
character(0)
character(0)
character(0)
character(0)
character(0)
character(0)
character(0)
character(0)
character(0)
character(0)
character(0)
character(0)
character(0)
character(0)
character(0)
character(0)
character(0)
character(0)
character(0)
character(0)
character(0)
There were 22 warnings (use warnings() to see them)
```

I am not quite sure why the for loop is not working. Any advice is welcome. Also, is a for loop the best option to achieve what I am trying to do?

Comment: Try running `loads.df$i`. You'll need to do `loads.df[[i]]` or similar instead.

Comment: Thanks Frank, that did it.